# How Create An Iterator for a Twitter Bootstrap Carousel in an Ember.js Template

Tags: javascript, html, twitter-bootstrap, ember.js

I am using Ember.js to generate a [Twitter Bootstrap Carousel](http://twitter.github.io/bootstrap/javascript.html#carousel). I am iterating over an `ArrayController`, but I have run into a problem: the Carousel requires a `data-slide-to` for each item that is iterated from 0 upwards (0, 1, 2, etc.). How can I easily create this with Ember?

Another, follow-up question: how can I set the class of ONLY the first item of iteration to `active` with Ember?

(my controller is in the default format, so it is generated)

**Relevant Template:**

```
<script type="text/x-handlebars" id="featured">
    <div class="span8">
      <div id="featured" class="carousel slide">
        <ol class="carousel-indicators">
          {{#each article in controller}}
            <li data-target="#featured" data-slide-to="0" class="active"></li>
          {{/each}}
        </ol>
        <div class="carousel-inner">
          {{#each controller}}
            <div class="active item">
              <div class="cover-photo">
              {{renderPhoto coverPhoto.url}}
              </div>
              <div class="carousel-caption">
                <h4>{{title}}</h4>
                <p>derp derp durr hurr durr</p>
              </div>
            </div>
          {{/each}}
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </script>
```

Answer (score 1):

In your ArticlesController (create one), define `contentWithIndex` which includes the index of each article in `content`, and an `isFirst` property:

```
App.ArticlesController = Ember.ArrayController.extend({
  contentWithIndex: function() {
    var content = this.get('content') || [];

    return content.map(function(article, index) {
      return {
         article: article, 
         index: index,
         isFirst: (index === 0)
      } 
    });
  }.property('content.[]')
});
```

Then in your template:

```
{{#each controller.contentWithIndex}}
   <div {{bindAttr class=":item isFirst:active"}} 
        {{bindAttr data-slide-to="index"}}>
      <div class="cover-photo">
         {{renderPhoto article.coverPhoto.url}}
      </div>
      <div class="carousel-caption">
         <h4>{{article.title}}</h4>
         <p>derp derp durr hurr durr</p>
      </div>
   </div>
{{/each}}
```

Comment: It kind of works, although now I get an error whenever I try to scroll: `Uncaught TypeError: Object [object Object] has no method 'cycle' `. It is probably a Bootstrap error though...

Answer (score 1):

Leave your controller as is. If you have the array coming into your handlebars template named items, then you can achieve the carousel as below.

```handlebars

```
<p>There are {{items.length}} slides</p>
<ol class="carousel-indicators">
    {{#each items}}
    <li data-target="#urs" data-slide-to="{{@index}}" class="{{#unless @index}}active{{/unless}}"></li>
    {{/each}}
</ol>

<div class="carousel-inner">
{{#each items}}
    <div class="item {{#unless @index}}active{{/unless}}">
        <img src="{{this.image}}" alt="">
        <div class="container">
            <div class="carousel-caption">
                <h1>{{this.headline}}</h1>
                <p class="lead">{{this.body}}</p>
                <a class="btn btn-large btn-primary" href="#">{{this.button}}</a>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
{{/each}}
</div>

<a class="left carousel-control" href="#urs" data-slide="prev">&lsaquo;</a>
<a class="right carousel-control" href="#urs" data-slide="next">&rsaquo;</a>

<script>
    $('.slide').carousel({
        interval: 1000
    });
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Regarding your follow up, I ensured only the first slide has an active class by setting a custom view class on all the slides and checking if they're the first in didInsertElement thusly:

```
    App.CarouselView = Ember.View.extend
        layout: require '../../../templates/components/carousel'
        classNames: ['carousel', 'slide']
        didInsertElement: ->
            element = $(@$()).carousel interval: false
            element.on 'slid', =>
                @set 'currentSlide', element.data('carousel').getActiveIndex() + 1
        currentSlide: 1
        controlHref: (->
                '#' + @get('elementId')
            ).property 'elementId'    

        slidesView: Ember.CollectionView.extend
            contentBinding: 'parentView.slides'
            classNames: ['carousel-inner']    

            itemViewClass: Ember.View.extend
                classNames: ['item']
                slidesBinding: 'parentView.content'
                didInsertElement: ->
                    # Bootstrap carousels require that the first slide has the 'active' class.
                    if @get('slides.firstObject') is @get('context')
                        @$().addClass 'active'
```